# How to use findOneAndUpdate in MongoDB in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Say previously I had inserted a document into a mongo collection.

```
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
      if(err) {throw err;}
      else {
        document = {action: "alert",
                    protocol: "udp",
                    port: "80",
                    _id: "12" }
        var collection = db.collection("connections");
        collection.insertOne(document, function(err,result){
          if (err) {throw err;}
          else {
            console.log("Successful")
            db.close();
          }
        }
      }
```

Now I want to update the protocol field. What I have with no luck so far is

```
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
       if (err) { throw err; }
       else {
         var collection = db.collection("connections");
         collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "12"}, {$set: {protocol: "http"}}, {new: true}, function(err,doc) {
           if (err) { throw err; }
           else { console.log("Updated"); }
         });  
       }
     });
```

Am I passing the wrong parameters to the findOneAndUpdate method? I connect to the database correctly.

Comment: Are you actually defining the _id as "12"? Or are you accepting Mongo's ObjectId? If the latter, you aren't finding the document because you are passing a string as the _id in your query rather than an ObjectId instance. Also, what's the error look like? Finally --- why `{new: true}`?

Comment: Do you use Mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) or anything similar ? Usualy it's what people use for node.js. Do you have any error message ?

Comment: I'm using mongodb for node. And it isn't an _id error as it updates correctly it just replaces the entire document with protocol only.

Comment: Works fine when I try it with v2.1.18 of the native driver. But relu is right about `new` not being a valid option with the native driver (but it's just ignored).

Comment: As stated, `new` is not a MongoDB option (it's a Mongoose option). For MongoDB, it's called [`returnOriginal`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) and should be `false` if you want the updated document to be returned.

Answer (score 18):

I think you should try

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
   if (err) { throw err; }
   else {
     var collection = db.collection("connections");
     collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "12"}, {$set: {protocol: "http"}}, {upsert: true}, function(err,doc) {
       if (err) { throw err; }
       else { console.log("Updated"); }
     });  
   }
 });
```

If "upsert" set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria.

Answer (score 5):

=== Aug 2021

Here is an example of using `findOneAndUpdate` and getting back the updated document:

With the release of v4 of the node.js client, it seems the old solution of `returnOriginal: false` (which was awful anyway) is no longer the correct answer.

To see the list of available options for the node.js findOneAndUpdate method: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findoneandupdateoptions.html

But in short, this should work:

```js
const doc = await <Collection>.findOneAndUpdate(
  { ... search },
  {
    $set: {
      field1: 'value 1',
      field2: ['value 2'],
      etc.
    },
  },
  {
    upsert: true,
    returnDocument: 'after', // this is new !
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

your third `{new: true}` argument is not valid

Comment: should be returnOriginal: false (new is for mongoose, returnNewDocument for mongo console, and returnOriginal for the node module, awful

Answer (score 1):

```
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
   if (err) { throw err; }
   else {
     var collection = db.collection("connections");
     collection.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": "12"}, {$set: {"protocol": "http"}},  function(err,doc) {
       if (err) { throw err; }
       else { console.log("Updated"); }
     });  
   }
 });
```

Here to update the record,it is not needed to use  {upsert: true} and {new: true}. This solution works better.Try it once and suggest me if any errors in the code.

insert the update document if nothing matches the filter then use upsert.

Answer (score 0):

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
   if (err) { throw err; }
   else {
     var collection = db.collection("connections");
     collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "12"}, {protocol: "http"}, {new: true}, function(err,doc) {
       if (err) { throw err; }
       else { console.log("Updated"); }
     });  
   }
 });
```